# Passing Data from one page to another using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to formulate a url string from data on a checkout page. I need to take all the product codes, quantities and prices from items in a cart and create a string for use in affiliate tracking. This string needs to be rendered on the checkout page. Here's the html structure.

```
<span class="productCodeID">
<div class="productitemcell">123456</div>
<div class="productitemcell">789123</div>
</span>
<span class="productQuantityID">
<div class="productitemcell"><input type="text" value="3"></div>
<div class="productitemcell"><input type="text" value="1" ></div>
</span>
<span class="productPriceID">
<div class="productitemcell">$15.00</div>
<div class="productitemcell">$19.50</div>
</span>
```

What I need to build is this:

```
&skulist=123456,789123&pricelist=15.00,19.50&quantitylist=3,1
```

This string needs to be passed to the confirmation page. Just looking for a little guidance on how to accomplish this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function buildList(items, name) {
  var values = [];
  items.each(function() {
    values.push(this.value || $(this).text());
  });
  return name + '=' + values.join(',');
}

var result = [
  buildList($('.productCodeID > .productitemcell'), 'skulist'),
  buildList($('.productQuantityID > .productitemcell > input'), 'quantitylist'),
  buildList($('.productPriceID > .productitemcell'), 'pricelist')
];

var string = result.join('&');
```

[Working example on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ixemo4/edit)

Comment: Will this value be cached? The build is happening on the cart page. I need to display the result on the checkout page. Any suggestions on how to pass that data to a different page??

Comment: @mmsa: Just append it to the URL of the checkout page.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this (*verbose*)

```
var skulist = [], pricelist = [], quantitylist = [];

 $('.productCodeID .productitemcell').each(function(){
 skulist.push( $(this).text() );
});
$('.productQuantityID .productitemcell input').each(function(){
 pricelist.push( $(this).val() );
});
$('.productPriceID .productitemcell').each(function(){
  quantitylist.push( $(this).text().replace('$','') );
});

query = '&skulist=' + skulist.join(',') +
    '&pricelist=' + pricelist.join(',') +
    '&quantitylist=' + quantitylist.join(',');
```

Example code at http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/792xP/

Answer (score 0):

I query html elements and concat their value to String.

```
<input type="button" value="nextPage" onclick="nextPage();">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function nextPage(){
        // productCode
        var qs = '&skulist=';
        $.each($('span.productCodeID div'), function(){
            qs += $(this).html()+',';
        });
        qs = qs.substr(0, qs.length-1);

        // price
        qs += '&pricelist='
        $.each($('span.productPriceID div'), function(){
            qs += $(this).html().substr(1)+',';
        });
        qs = qs.substr(0, qs.length-1);

        // quantity
        qs += '&quantitylist='
        $.each($('span.productQuantityID div input'), function(){
            qs += $(this).val()+',';
        });
        qs = qs.substr(0, qs.length-1);

        // jump to nextPage
        location.href = 'nextpage.html' + qs;
    }
</script>
```